# How to mix Java Swing and JavaFX in Swing application?

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, javafx, rich-internet-application

I am developing a Java Swing application but I want to also use JavaFX with Swing. Is there any resource for that told how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2364553&tstart=0). The short story is that embedding JavaFX in Swing is now possible and supported via [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html), but the other direction is not supported.

Comment: FYI: It is completely unsupported, uses private APIs, and almost certainly will break in the next version.

Comment: FYI: Both link are now broken.

Answer (score 1):

The "JavaFX in Swing" link given above only works with JavaFX 1.1. Here is how to do it in JavaFX 1.2 [JavaFX in Swing - 1.2](http://blogs.oracle.com/clarkeman/entry/how_to_use_javafx_in). However, as Rastislav mentioned above, this is also using private APIs and will most likely break in the next major version. [JFXtras](http://jfxtras.org) has added some classes to support this, and hopefully, this will insulate the developer from the underlying release changes.

Comment: I think so. For now the best way how to do this is just wait.